# AR(p) selection

Tags: time-series, model-selection, stata, autoregressive, lags

I am facing difficulty in determining what AR(p) model to specify for my regression. By trial and error depicted below, it seems to me that an AR(4) model should be specified.

```
. reg r L.r

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,347
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 2345)      =    854.20
       Model |  215.345089         1  215.345089   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  591.179315     2,345  .252102053   R-squared       =    0.2670
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2667
       Total |  806.524404     2,346  .343787043   Root MSE        =     .5021

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           r |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           r |
         L1. |   .5165801    .017675    29.23   0.000       .48192    .5512403
             |
       _cons |   .0002531   .0103641     0.02   0.981    -.0200706    .0205769
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. actest, robust

Cumby-Huizinga test for autocorrelation
  H0: variable is MA process up to order q
  HA: serial correlation present at specified lags >q
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  H0: q=0 (serially uncorrelated)        |  H0: q=specified lag-1
  HA: s.c. present at range specified    |  HA: s.c. present at lag specified
-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------
    lags   |      chi2      df     p-val | lag |      chi2      df     p-val
-----------+-----------------------------+-----+-----------------------------
   1 -  1  |     72.136      1    0.0000 |   1 |     72.136      1    0.0000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Test allows predetermined regressors/instruments
  Test robust to heteroskedasticity

. reg r L(1/2).r

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,346
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 2343)      =    502.98
       Model |  242.009015         2  121.004507   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  563.671128     2,343  .240576666   R-squared       =    0.3004
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2998
       Total |  805.680142     2,345  .343573621   Root MSE        =    .49049

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           r |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           r |
         L1. |   .4050162   .0201763    20.07   0.000     .3654511    .4445814
         L2. |   .2148748   .0201672    10.65   0.000     .1753273    .2544222
             |
       _cons |   .0004264   .0101266     0.04   0.966    -.0194316    .0202844
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. actest, robust

Cumby-Huizinga test for autocorrelation
  H0: variable is MA process up to order q
  HA: serial correlation present at specified lags >q
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  H0: q=0 (serially uncorrelated)        |  H0: q=specified lag-1
  HA: s.c. present at range specified    |  HA: s.c. present at lag specified
-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------
    lags   |      chi2      df     p-val | lag |      chi2      df     p-val
-----------+-----------------------------+-----+-----------------------------
   1 -  1  |     24.707      1    0.0000 |   1 |     24.707      1    0.0000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Test allows predetermined regressors/instruments
  Test robust to heteroskedasticity

. reg r L(1/3).r

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,345
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 2341)      =    350.83
       Model |  249.790432         3  83.2634773   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  555.593235     2,341  .237331583   R-squared       =    0.3102
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3093
       Total |  805.383667     2,344  .343593715   Root MSE        =    .48717

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           r |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           r |
         L1. |   .3792806   .0205235    18.48   0.000     .3390345    .4195267
         L2. |    .166328   .0216949     7.67   0.000     .1237849    .2088712
         L3. |   .1196588   .0205112     5.83   0.000     .0794368    .1598807
             |
       _cons |   .0004293   .0100602     0.04   0.966    -.0192986    .0201571
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. actest, robust

Cumby-Huizinga test for autocorrelation
  H0: variable is MA process up to order q
  HA: serial correlation present at specified lags >q
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  H0: q=0 (serially uncorrelated)        |  H0: q=specified lag-1
  HA: s.c. present at range specified    |  HA: s.c. present at lag specified
-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------
    lags   |      chi2      df     p-val | lag |      chi2      df     p-val
-----------+-----------------------------+-----+-----------------------------
   1 -  1  |      8.350      1    0.0039 |   1 |      8.350      1    0.0039
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Test allows predetermined regressors/instruments
  Test robust to heteroskedasticity

. reg r L(1/4).r

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,344
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 2339)      =    268.14
       Model |  253.178313         4  63.2945781   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  552.116947     2,339  .236048289   R-squared       =    0.3144
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3132
       Total |   805.29526     2,343  .343702629   Root MSE        =    .48585

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           r |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           r |
         L1. |   .3706284   .0206157    17.98   0.000     .3302014    .4110555
         L2. |   .1549074   .0219103     7.07   0.000     .1119418    .1978729
         L3. |   .0928425   .0219076     4.24   0.000     .0498822    .1358027
         L4. |   .0720645   .0206045     3.50   0.000     .0316596    .1124695
             |
       _cons |   .0001068   .0100351     0.01   0.992    -.0195718    .0197855
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. actest, robust

Cumby-Huizinga test for autocorrelation
  H0: variable is MA process up to order q
  HA: serial correlation present at specified lags >q
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  H0: q=0 (serially uncorrelated)        |  H0: q=specified lag-1
  HA: s.c. present at range specified    |  HA: s.c. present at lag specified
-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------
    lags   |      chi2      df     p-val | lag |      chi2      df     p-val
-----------+-----------------------------+-----+-----------------------------
   1 -  1  |      1.225      1    0.2684 |   1 |      1.225      1    0.2684
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Test allows predetermined regressors/instruments
  Test robust to heteroskedasticity
```

ACTEST command suggests AR(4) to be specified, I then carry out Breusch-Godfrey test to see if the selection of the two tests agree with each other.

```
. reg r L(1/4).r

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,344
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 2339)      =    268.14
       Model |  253.178313         4  63.2945781   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  552.116947     2,339  .236048289   R-squared       =    0.3144
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3132
       Total |   805.29526     2,343  .343702629   Root MSE        =    .48585

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           r |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           r |
         L1. |   .3706284   .0206157    17.98   0.000     .3302014    .4110555
         L2. |   .1549074   .0219103     7.07   0.000     .1119418    .1978729
         L3. |   .0928425   .0219076     4.24   0.000     .0498822    .1358027
         L4. |   .0720645   .0206045     3.50   0.000     .0316596    .1124695
             |
       _cons |   .0001068   .0100351     0.01   0.992    -.0195718    .0197855
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estat bgodfrey

Breusch-Godfrey LM test for autocorrelation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    lags(p)  |          chi2               df                 Prob > chi2
-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
       1     |          7.146               1                   0.0075
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        H0: no serial correlation

. reg r L(1/5).r

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,343
-------------+----------------------------------   F(5, 2337)      =    217.60
       Model |  253.895887         5  50.7791773   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  545.359929     2,337  .233358977   R-squared       =    0.3177
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3162
       Total |  799.255815     2,342   .34127063   Root MSE        =    .48307

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           r |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           r |
         L1. |   .3662664   .0205618    17.81   0.000     .3259452    .4065876
         L2. |   .1551372   .0218684     7.09   0.000     .1122537    .1980207
         L3. |   .0937314    .022019     4.26   0.000     .0505525    .1369103
         L4. |   .0703822   .0218659     3.22   0.001     .0275036    .1132607
         L5. |   .0109803   .0205456     0.53   0.593    -.0293091    .0512698
             |
       _cons |  -.0010002   .0099799    -0.10   0.920    -.0205707    .0185702
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estat bgodfrey

Breusch-Godfrey LM test for autocorrelation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    lags(p)  |          chi2               df                 Prob > chi2
-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
       1     |         22.015               1                   0.0000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        H0: no serial correlation

. reg r L(1/6).r

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     2,342
-------------+----------------------------------   F(6, 2335)      =    181.23
       Model |  251.154059         6  41.8590099   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  539.330146     2,335  .230976508   R-squared       =    0.3177
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3160
       Total |  790.484206     2,341   .33766946   Root MSE        =     .4806

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           r |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           r |
         L1. |   .3555388   .0205829    17.27   0.000     .3151761    .3959014
         L2. |   .1525293   .0218011     7.00   0.000     .1097778    .1952809
         L3. |   .0918417   .0219918     4.18   0.000     .0487162    .1349672
         L4. |   .0658227   .0219911     2.99   0.003     .0226985    .1089468
         L5. |    -.00477   .0218076    -0.22   0.827    -.0475342    .0379943
         L6. |   .0498962   .0204418     2.44   0.015     .0098103    .0899821
             |
       _cons |  -.0019319    .009931    -0.19   0.846    -.0214064    .0175426
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estat bgodfrey

Breusch-Godfrey LM test for autocorrelation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    lags(p)  |          chi2               df                 Prob > chi2
-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
       1     |          2.459               1                   0.1169
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        H0: no serial correlation
```

Confusing enough, Breusch-Godfrey test suggests an AR(6) model to be specified. Why is there a difference between them?

For all it's worth, I attach my ACF and PACF.
[image]
[image]

Upon request, below is a (9 years) line plot of my dependant variable, CSAD, a measure of dispersion between market return and individual return, hence effectively capturing herding if the two parameters are similar.
[image]

Comment: Can you also post a plot of your actual time series? How long is the time series and how often is it measured? Does it have any missing values? This should help give more context to your question.

Comment: Isabella, thanks for your reply. I have attached a line plot as requested.

Comment: please post the actual data in a csv file not a line plot

Comment: IrishStat, my apologies but I do not know how to attach a CSV file here, would you mind enlightening me on it? By the way, my data is a 9 year financial daily data and it does not have any missing values.